# How would I be able to convert table structured data to a dict/graph structure in python/pandas, to be used for force graphs in D3?

Tags: python, pandas, d3.js, graph, dataframe

I'm stuck in converting this csv:

```
"","Destination","Source"
"1","New York","Chicago"
"2","Denver","Chicago"
"3","Los Angeles","Boston"
"4","Colorado","Indianapolis"
```

to a format like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Chicago",
        "target": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "New York",
        "target": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Denver",
        "target": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Los Angeles",
        "target": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Boston",
        "target": [
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Indianapolis",
        "target": [
            6
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Colorado",
        "target": []
    }
]
```

where target is the index number of the node its connected to.

I'm trying to do this in python because I want to post this data to a DB and pull from the front end to do D3 stuff.

I tried with pandas too, but couldn't it in this format. pretty frustrated now! Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: Why some of your `target` is empty list? like for name New york the target will be 1

Comment: Hi, @Euler, thank you for your comment, I made an error in the CSV file headers, I've corrected it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), but before need create proper `df`:

```
df['nan'] = 'none'
df['Source'] = df.Source.astype(str)

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df = pd.lreshape(df, {'target': ['index', 'nan'], 'name': ['Destination', 'Source']})
print (df)
  target          name
0      1       Chicago
1      2       Chicago
2      3        Boston
3      4  Indianapolis
4   none      New York
5   none        Denver
6   none   Los Angeles
7   none      Colorado

df1 = df.groupby('name')['target']
        .apply(lambda x: [] if (x == 'none').all() else x.tolist())
        .reset_index(name='target'))

print (df1)
           name  target
0        Boston     [3]
1       Chicago  [1, 2]
2      Colorado      []
3        Denver      []
4  Indianapolis     [4]
5   Los Angeles      []
6      New York      []
```

```
print (df1.to_dict(orient='records'))
[{'name': 'Boston', 'target': [3]}, 
 {'name': 'Chicago', 'target': [1, 2]}, 
 {'name': 'Colorado', 'target': []}, 
 {'name': 'Denver', 'target': []}, 
 {'name': 'Indianapolis', 'target': [4]},
 {'name': 'Los Angeles', 'target': []}, 
 {'name': 'New York', 'target': []}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this does what you want

```
import csv
reader=csv.reader(open("data.csv","rb"))
next(reader)
x,y={},set()
for r in reader:
    a,b,c=r
    x.update({a:c})
    y.update([b,c])

anss =dict((new_key,[k for k,v in x.iteritems() if new_key==v]) for new_key in y)
result=[{"name":k,"target":v} for k,v in anss.iteritems()]
```